# How do I normalize RGB in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing, normalization

I need to normalize an RGB image.
I have the code for grayscale normalization, but it doesn't works.
Is it possible to first perform an update on an RGB image?
I attach the code for normalization on grayscales

```py
img = cv2.imread("055_GT2_IN_F_LI_01_4.jpg",0)
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    res = numpy.hstack((img, equ))

    # show image input vs output
    cv2.imshow('image', res)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return img,equ
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly with it doesn't work?

Comment: does not work for RGB images.

Comment: Again, what does not work?

Comment: normalization does not work for color images (RGB), only for grayscale images. In the meantime, I was wondering if it would be possible to perform such an operation on this type of images.

Comment: Histogram equalization is not normalization. Normalization has to do with mean subtraction and division by standard deviation. If you want to equalize a color image, you can do that on each channel separately or you can convert to HSV (or  LAB or the like), equalize the intensity-like channel, then convert that channel with the original S and V channels back to RGB.

Answer (score 1):

Histogram normalization is only supported for grayscale images.
You can [cv::split()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0547c7fed86152d7e9d0096029c8518a) your image into separate channel, [cv::equalizeHist()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga7e54091f0c937d49bf84152a16f76d6e) them individually before [cv::merge()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4) them back together.

Comment: I'm not doing your homework for you ... check https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html which shows splitting, then merging ... just insert the equalizing for each channel in between.

Comment: Thank you, a no was enough!